# Using global.asax Application_PostAuthenticateRequest to manage password expiry

Tags: vb.net, forms-authentication

Visual Studio 2013, VB.NET 4.0, AJAXControlToolkit 4.1.7.930

I have the following code in my Global.asax for authenticating pages on my website as well as forcing password changes.

```
Sub Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    ' only want to evaluate stuff that is relevant to security
    If Not Request.Path.EndsWith("About.aspx") _
        And Not Request.Path.EndsWith(".css") _
        And Not Request.Path.EndsWith(".jpg") _
        And Not Request.Path.EndsWith(".gif") _
        And Not Request.Path.EndsWith(".png") Then

        If Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath = "~/" Then
            HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("Login.aspx")
        End If

        ' Check if there password has expired or they are a brand new user,
        '  if so force a password change
        If User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then

            ' user authenticated

            Dim Usr = Membership.GetUser()
            Dim PasswordExpiryDays As Int16 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("PasswordExpiryDays")

            If Not Usr Is Nothing Then

                ' was the last time the password changed the date the account was created?
                ' Or is it expired?    
                If Usr.LastPasswordChangedDate.AddDays(PasswordExpiryDays) < Now _
                        Or Usr.LastPasswordChangedDate = Usr.CreationDate Then

                    'they need to change their password, 
                    '  make sure we aren't on a ChangePassword page already!
                    If Not Request.Path.EndsWith("ChangePassword.aspx") Then

                        ' since users will already be logged in if they try to do a normal PasswordChange.aspx
                        ' we can assume that all failed authentications need to go to the Login process
                        '  (and go through the 'Check for Application Invites' process)
                        Try
                            Server.Transfer("~/LoginChangePassword.aspx")
                        Catch ex As Exception

                            ' if the server.transfer fails, try response.redirect
                            Response.Redirect("~/LoginChangePassword.aspx")
                        End Try


                    End If

                Else
                    ' Authenticated but don't need to change their password.
                End If
            End If

        Else
            ' user is not authenticated, let Membership handle getting them logged in.

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Everything works great except this situation:
If I log in with an expired password I am redirected to LoginChangePassword.aspx... that's expected. This page has an asp:ChangePassword control. If the user successfully changes their password on the first try they are allowed to continue on into the website. If for some reason the user refreshes the page they get errors and nothing works anymore.

Specifically Chrome reports errors like: a ton of "unexpected token <" errors but what was of interest was a "ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load. ". I was able to track it down to the fact that my code in the Application_PostAuthenticateRequest was catching the processing of ScriptResource.axd and WebResource.axd files and redirecting back to the LoginChangePassword.aspx page (the one that I'm on!). Why it's generating the errors the second time around, I don't know.

But I did find a way to "fix" it. In the opening IF statement, if I also skip processing ScriptResource.axd and WebResource.axd files everything works fine.

So my question is, am I missing something about file security and the .axd files? Is it ok to continue to ignore whether these .axd files are being processed by an authenticated user?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.axd files are script resources, so for a reliable check, you only should do a redirect for the following type text/html

If req.AcceptTypes IsNot Nothing And req.AcceptTypes.Length > 0 AndAlso req.AcceptTypes(0)   ="text/html" Then
      ... your stuff here
   End If

Comment: [Request.AcceptTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.accepttypes(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a list of browser supported types. I need to know what type the current page is, not what types the browser supports. Then I need to know if it's a page I want to run an authentication against.